# convert html table to excel .it's work fine in ie9 but not work in ie10,ie11 and other version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

convert html table to excel it is work fine in ie9 but not work in ie10,Ie11 and other version

```
<script Language="javascript">
    function clock(id, event) {
        //Get table
        var tab = document.getElementById(id)
        var table = $(tab)[0];

        //Get number of rows/columns
        var rowLength = table.rows.length;
        var colLength = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        //Declare string to fill with table data
        var tableString = "";

        //Get column headers
        for (var i = 0; i < colLength; i++) {
            tableString += table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.split(",").join("") + ",";
        }

        tableString = tableString.substring(0, tableString.length - 1);
        tableString += "\r\n";

        //Get row data
        for (var j = 1; j < rowLength; j++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < colLength; k++) {
                tableString += table.rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML.split(",").join("") + ",";
            }
            tableString += "\r\n";
        }

        //Save file
        if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
            //Optional: If you run into delimiter issues (where the commas are not interpreted and all data is one cell), then use this line to manually specify the delimeter
            tableString = 'sep=,\r\n' + tableString;

            myFrame.document.open("text/html", "replace");
            myFrame.document.write(tableString);
            myFrame.document.close();
            myFrame.focus();
            myFrame.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, 'data.csv');
        } else {
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(tableString);
            $(event.target).attr({
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank',
                'download': 'my_data.csv'
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do yo u get any error message?

Comment: no .there is no error msg